# What does 'module' object has no attribute 'draw' mean? How do I fix it?

Tags: python, canopy, image-editing, image-editor

I am new to computer coding. We work with Canopy to do PYTHON and we are doing image modification. I have a 'module' object has no attribute 'draw' error and am not sure how to fix it. I have imported the following:

```
import PIL
import os.path  
import PIL.ImageDraw            
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
```

And the code I am trying to run is:

```
def round_corners_of_all_images(directory=None):
    """ Saves a modfied version of each image in directory.

    Uses current directory if no directory is specified. 
    Places images in subdirectory 'modified', creating it if it does not exist.
    New image files are of type PNG and have transparent rounded corners.
    """

    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd() # Use working directory if unspecified

    # Create a new directory 'modified'
    new_directory = os.path.join(directory, 'modified')
    try:
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    except OSError:
        pass # if the directory already exists, proceed  

    #load all the images
    image_list, file_list = get_images(directory)  

    #go through the images and save modified versions
    for n in range(len(image_list)):
        # Parse the filename
        filename, filetype = file_list[n].split('.')

        # drawing the text on the picture
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_list[n])
        font = ImageFont.truetype("Infinite_Stroke",size=24,index=0,encoding="unic")
        draw.text((10, 25),(0,0,255),"SAMSUNG", font=font)

        # Round the corners with radius = 30% of short side
        new_image = round_corners(image_list[n],.30)
        #save the altered image, suing PNG to retain transparency
        new_image_filename = os.path.join(new_directory, filename + '.jpg')
        new_image.save(new_image_filename)
```

Comment: I believe you just have incorrect capitalization: `draw = ImageDraw.draw(image_list[n])` -> `draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_list[n])`

Comment: I tried that and I still am receiving the same message.

Comment: Don't _describe_ your error -- copy and paste the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation it looks like the method you are looking for is Draw(), not draw()

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html

Try this

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_list[n])
```

Comment: I tried that and I still am receiving the same message.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the new code? I find it very weird that you would still get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe try a pip install PIL again? Check if you have the module installed in a directory you can access? I can't think of anything else

Answer (score 0):

Old question but maybe still relevant answer: the error here is in the double import of ImageDraw, rewriting the imports in the following way salved the problem on my end:

```
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw
```